# Colors in `ParametricPlot` are inconsistent

Tags: plotting, graphics

Why are the colors in the second plot different from those in the first plot? Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

```
Table[{a (t - Sin[t]), a (1 - Cos[t])}, {a, 1, 3}]

(* {{t - Sin[t], 1 - Cos[t]}, 
   {2 (t - Sin[t]), 2 (1 - Cos[t])}, 
   {3 (t - Sin[t]), 3 (1 - Cos[t])}} *)

ParametricPlot[{{t - Sin[t], 1 - Cos[t]}, 
                {2 (t - Sin[t]), 2 (1 - Cos[t])}, 
                {3 (t - Sin[t]), 3 (1 - Cos[t])}}, 
      {t, 0, 6 \[Pi]}, 
      PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}, {Thick, Red}, {Thick, Green}}]
```

[image]

```
ParametricPlot[Table[{a (t - Sin[t]), a (1 - Cos[t])}, {a, 1, 3}], 
      {t, 0, 6 \[Pi]}, 
      PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}, {Thick, Red}, {Thick, Green}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Add option `Evaluated->True` to the second `ParametricPlot`

Comment: Alternatively, `ParametricPlot[Evaluate@Table[ ... ], ... ]` This is necessary since `ParametricPlot` (and other plot functions) have the attribute `HoldAll`